# How can fetch the text from html tag in meteor template event?

Tags: jquery, templates, meteor, dom-events, meteor-helper

How can I get "option 1" from below code:

```
<template name="MyTemplate">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
         <form method="post" id="some-form" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Select Option</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
                     <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
                     <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
                     <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-disable-with="Saving..." class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I am using chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for style. So, dropdown node converts differently  and there one node is like:

```
<a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
    <span>Option 1</span>
</a>
```

Which holds the selected value from the dropdown.

Inside template event my code is:

```
template.find("#some-form .chosen-single span");
```

It is giving me:

```
<span>Option 1</span>
```

I want "Option 1" from it. if I write like this:

```
// giving "undefined"
template.find("#some-form .chosen-single span").html; 
or
// giving error :: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
template.find("#some-form .chosen-single span").html();
```

Comment: `template.find("#some-form .div-class span").html();` should work. can you reproduce the problem somewhere?

Comment: there is some problem with your template, Can you show us that code which contains your template.

Comment: or try `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: Where is your span in html ? or hello ??

Comment: There are no `.div-class span` elements.

Comment: `template.$("#some-form .div-class span").html()` should work

Comment: Sorry guys...now question is ok..actually i am using "chosen" [link](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for style. @rohit-arora

Comment: np. I've created answer for this question below so You can mark it as accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template.find("#some-form .chosen-single span").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for all other infos explained in this doc: 
http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#eventmaps

but for me this code works (meteor 1.1.0.3)
html:

```
<template name="newTextLabel">
      <span class="label label-primary pull-right genre">{{this}}</span>
</template>
```

event:

```
Template.newTextLabel.events ({
    'click .genre': function(event) {
     sAlert.info('test: ' + event.target.textContent);
    //  Router.go('somePath', {
    //   _id: this.genrePath
    //  });

   }
})
```